# Find minimum of scipy.interpolate.Rbf

Tags: python, scipy, max, interpolation, min

I'm interpolating a dataset using scipy.interpolate, which gives a heatmap (z values as a function of x, y):

```
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='cubic')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)
```

Finding the shape reveals:

```
zi.shape = (150L, 150L)
```

How can I find the minimum and maximum values of `zi`?

Comment: `numpy.min(zi)`, `numpy.max(zi)`? Note that you can also use `scipy.optimize.minimize()` to search for the actual extrema of the interpolating function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finding minimum: `np.min(zi)`
finding maximum: `np.max(zi)`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11626895)

Comment: @jezrael actually, this is the answer to the question (which explains why I only commented on it)

Comment: I posted the answer shortly after, then deleted it because it seemed trivial. Looking back, it wasn't apparent to me. I tried `scipy.optimize.minimize()`, but couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: That would mean using something like `res=scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda xy: rbf(*xy),[x0,y0])` where you've determined `[x0,y0]` from your current solution with a rough mesh. If course if your function has only single extrema, you can choose any reasonable starting point. And this will find you the minimum position, `res.x`, so the actual minimum would be `rbf(*res.x)`. And you can find the maximum by minimizing `-rbf()`. If this doesn't help and you really need it, let me know and I'll add an answer.